# Twitter+linkedin Issue in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an application with facebook,twitter and linkedin integrating to it.But when i am using twitter and linkedin it is causing some problem.I found some results in stack saying

remove the library files of linkedin sdk and add the source files of it with oAuth files from twiiter sdk then it works ok for linkedin
then I integrate all twitter code then project run ok without error but for twitter login interface it shows "PAGE NOT FOUND" 
But then Notice that I have given the same key and secret to both linkedin and twitter after changing them it solved
But can u please suggest  how to do this.it is so confusing.thats why i am going for a clear picture.Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of integrating Facebook & Twiter into you application seperately, you can use ShareKit. It supports:

- Delicious
- Email
- Facebook
- Google Reader
- Instapaper
- Pinboard
- Read It Later
- Tumblr
- Twitter

Get the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit).

I have no idea about LinkedIn.